Did Kunti kill Karna (for herself , in her mind) when she threw away Karna in the river?
Kunti after giving birth to Karna, threw him in the river.
I want to know if Kunti was sure that Karna will be protected or she didn't care if Karna will remain alive or he would get drowned and die ?
Can someone quote that part of the story here ?

If she did not care for his life, Karna would have been thrown into water without a cradle or into a some dangerous forest. She was more afraid of disreputation as an unwed queen.

Kunti was concerned for Karna's safety.

Kunti prayed to all the gods to protect Karna -


'O child, may good betide you at the hands of all that inhabit the
land, the water, the sky, and the celestial regions. May all your
paths be auspicious! May no one obstruct your way! And, O son,
may all that come across you have their hearts divested of hostility
towards you: And may that lord of waters, Varuna protect you in
water! And may the deity that ranges the skies completely protect
you in the sky. And may, O son, that best of those that impart heat,
viz., Surya, your father, and from whom I have obtained you as
ordained by Destiny, protect you everywhere! And may the Adityas and
the Vasus, the Rudras and the Sadhyas, the Visvadevas and the Maruts,
and the cardinal points with the great Indra and the regents presiding
over them, and, indeed, all the celestials, protect you in every
place!'


Section CCCVI, Pativrata Mahatmya, Mahabharata.

